# how to audioread mp3 files one after the other from the same folder in Matlab? Is using "for" loop helpful?

Tags: matlab, audio

If I have mp3 files in one folder in Matlab , and I want to use the command `audioread` in a way that will make the mp3s play one after the other.
I used the following:

```
[y,fs]=audioread('001.mp3')
sound(y,fs)
```

This plays the sound for a signal mp3 what function or thing I can do to make the next mp3 to play after each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities. Assuming you have multiple audio files with the same sampling rate, you can simply append them:

```
sound([y1;y2],fs1)
```

Another alternative is to use `pause` to wait until the first sound has finished:

```
sound(y1,fs1);
pause(size(y1,1)/fs);
sound(y2,fs2);
```